# Is it theoretically possible to create a free software WinRAR compressor?

Tags: united-states, open-source-software

Please forgive me if this has already been answered somewhere; I searched high and low and found quite a few answers dealing with the RAR file format but none that answered this specific question.

Is it *theoretically* possible to create a fully Free Software (i.e. GPL or similar) program that *compresses* RAR?

I am already aware of the hairy licensing issues surrounding the unrar code and the end user license agreement that supposedly prevents reverse-engineering of the binaries and usage of the unrar source to create a compression routine.

But suppose one has only an existing RAR archive in their possession. Having *never seen the RAR binaries or unrar source* (i.e., clean-room reverse engineering), **would one be legally able to create a completely free decompression AND compression routine for RAR**?

Comment: RAR is more than a file format, it's a set of algorithms which are copyrighted. You are basically asking that if you independently recreate a copyrighted work, does the copyright still belong to the original author?

Comment: Algorithms can't be copyrighted, only patented (and not in all jurisdictions, as I recall). Specific expressions of an algorithm can be copyrighted, but anybody else can implement an identical algorithm as long as they don't copy any copyrighted work (that's the basic point of copyright). @RonBeyer

Comment: Sory can somebody explain how that clean-room reverse engineering should be prooved? I can say I´ve used clean-room reverse engineering even if I didn´t.

Comment: @Convert: That might be a good question by itself. I see you're a new user, you may want to check the [help for new users](https://law.stackexchange.com/help). It probably matters _where_ you need to prove it, so include that in your question. Which type of court in which country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists a "free software" unarchiver for RAR archives. The Mac unarchiving software "The Unarchiver" (the latest version is proprietary but older versions until 2017 were LGPL), as well as its cross-platform command-line version "unar", implemented extraction of RARv3 files in free software starting [in 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722095811/http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html). See the Free Software Foundation announcement [here](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/free-rarv3-extraction). The last free software version of The Unarchiver [supported](https://web.archive.org/web/20170706222632/http://unarchiver.c3.cx/changes) extraction of RARv5 archives.

I am not exactly sure how they managed to write a free software implementation of RAR extraction. Perhaps it was some kind of "clean room" reimplementation? But presumably the same technique can be used to implement RAR archiving.

Comment: I've heard of unar. I guess the question remains, could one legally use this code (which has no relation to the official unrar source published by Roshal) to develop the compression routine?

It seems like the INTENT is for no one to develop compression software except for WinRAR themselves, but I don't think it's legally possible to demand that unless the algorithm itself is patented.

The use of the official unrar source is obviously off-limits due to the license, but if a clean-room re-implementation of the compression algorithm is possible I'm surprised no one has done it yet.

Comment: @slickdeveloper: Since the pre-2017 code from The Unarchiver/unar is LGPL, you should be able to use it to develop any other LGPL software you want, although I am not sure whether there is enough information in the decompression code to figure out how to do compression.

Comment: OK, I've accepted this answer, sorry it took so long. It may be that it simply isn't possible to reverse-engineer the compression routine from the decompression routine. And I see no references to a "UnRAR exception" in the unar source tree. Thanks!